# how to get the annotation ID and set the size and font of the annotation?

Tags: annotations, dm-script

I create some annotation, but I do not know how to control the size and font of the annotation, both command `setannotationsize` and `setannotationfont` ask the annotationID, there is no explanation how to get annotationID.

```
image img1:=getfrontimage()
img1.createtextannotation(50,50,"this is HRTEM image")


setAnnotationFont( Image, Number annotationID, String fontName ) 
void SetAnnotationSize( Image, Number annotationID, Number size )
```

Answer (score 0):

### The short answer:

> When using any annotation-creating command you can see that the method's signature has a numeric return value, f.e.:
>
> `RealNumber CreateTextAnnotation(BasicImage img, RealNumber top, RealNumber left, String text)`
>
> The returned value is your *annotationID*.

---

### However, there is more to the story...

DM-scripting often has simplified wrapper-commands for the beginners which expose only a part of the functionality. This is for example the case for the simplified `Get/Set...Note()` type commands. And it also true for the annotation commands you've mentioned. These simplified commands makes it easier to achieve simple things with only one command, but if you want more, it is good to go to the proper "underlying" script objects and object hierarchy.

> *Annotations* are really `Component` objects, so you need to refer to the help section on `components` for all of the commands you need.

[image: F1 help]

There (at the bottom) you will find commands like

`Component NewTextAnnotation( Number left, Number top, String text, Number size )`

These commands do not return an ID, but the `component` itself. You can then modify the `component` with any of the described commands which take the `component` as a parameter, such as f.e.:

`void ComponentSetForegroundColor( Component comp, Number red_i, Number green_i, Number blue_i )`

But how do you add `components` to your images? You can't. Because an `image` really is just a number array you can display in different ways: As `RasterDisplay` or as `SpreadSheetDisplay` or as `SurfacePlotDisplay` for example.

What you really do, is to add a `component` to the *display* of an image!
Each (shown) `image` object has an `imageDisplay` object. So you add your `component` onto the `imageDisplay` object.

Now, the beauty of object-oriented coding is, that `imageDisplay` objects *also are* `component` *objects* at the same time. So the commands in the help on `components` also apply for `imageDisplays`. And these commands include those to get/set/add/remove children.

To sum up: The full story of adding annotations is: Create an annotation (as a `component`). Get the `image`. Get the `imageDisplay` from the image (which is also a `component`). Add the annotation `component` as a child to the `imageDisplay` `component`. Here is an example:

```
image img := RealImage( "Test",4,512,512)
img.ShowImage()
imageDisplay disp = img.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
component arrow = NewArrowAnnotation(110,110,280,400)
arrow.ComponentSetForeGroundColor(1,1,0)
disp.ComponentAddChildAtEnd( arrow )
```